# Delete last node from single-linked list

Tags: c++

I have to write a method that's going to delete the last node from the List. Do you guys have any ideas on how I should approach this?

Comment: I do not know c++, but logic is as below - while(node->next) node = node->next; delete node.

Comment: iterate to the end of the list, keeping a pointer to the previous item in the list. Set the previous item's next pointer to NULL (or whatever you use for no more links). Free the last item.

Comment: The field Node::next of the last node in your list should be a nullptr.

Comment: If I were in your shoes, I'd search the internet for something like "c++ delete node linked list".  But since I'm not, you'll just have to suffer.

Comment: If you are really using C++ and not C, you should be using the STL's `std::list` (double-linked) or `std::forward_list` (single-linked) container instead.

Comment: C++ has a standard `std::list`, `std::queue`, `std::stack`, they might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete the last element on a list all you need to do is maintain two separate nodes. Initially one should point to the head of the list and the other should point to the second element on the list. You should do something like the following :

```
if(head == NULL)
     return 0;
else if(head->next == NULL){
     Node *temp = head;
     delete temp;
     head = NULL;
}
else{
    Node *one = head;
    Node *two = head->next;
    while(two->next != NULL){
         two = two->next;
         one = one->next;
    }
    one->next = NULL;
    delete two;
}
```

Comment: This is if the list has 2 elements right? (two being the last element) or am I getting this wrong?

Comment: @BozhidarGrujoski The previous answer would work fine if the list has at-least two elements and this edited answer would work for lists of any length.

Comment: fails if head is NULL to begin with.

Comment: This also fails to delete the `head` node if there is only 1 node in the list.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a single-linked list, you have no choice but to iterate through the entire list to the last node, maintaining a pointer to the previous node so you can reset its `next` field when freeing the last node:

```
if (head)
{
    node *curNode = head;
    node *prevNode = NULL;

    while (curNode->next)
    {
        prevNode = curNode;
        curNode = curNode->next;
    }

    if (prevNode) prevNode->next = NULL;
    delete curNode;
}
```

If you were using a double-linked list instead, this would be easier, as you can keep a pointer to the last node in the list and just operate on it directly:

```
if (head == tail)
{
    delete head;
    head = tail = NULL;
}
else if (tail)
{
    node *curNode = tail;
    tail = curNode->previous; 
    tail->next = NULL;
    delete curNode;
}
```

Of course, if you are really using C++ then you should be using the STL's `std::list` (double-linked) or `std::forward_list` (single-linked) containers instead, which handle these details for you.